# how can i show standalone python game on web server page?

Tags: python, flask, pygame, brython

my first question.

I made a simple standalone game by using python3.x (old game - called 'pangpang')

so, i'm going to play this game on web page, but i cant apply this on web page.

now, i'm using python3 with flask, pip, pycharm, kali linux in virtual machine(Virtual box).

and i can play this game on local area.

here is my program steps.

1. init.py file starting flask server.
2. in init.py : `@app.route('/game'):`
   `return render_template('game.html')`
   => this looks like operate well, but i used brython in game.html file...
   => i think this file isn't work well.

In game.html file, i import brython js files

if you have any idea answer me please.

thanks

Comment: this is sources in game.html file head area

Comment: this is sources in game.html file head area
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.9/brython.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.9/brython.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.9/brython.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.8.9/brython_stdlib.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="brython()">
    <script type="text/python">
        import pygame

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).